# How to export states in hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Please, Could help me? I'd like exporting states registered in hybris and what is default to export anything? I always need export something inside him, but I haven't a base other export. In Stack site I got about access right, I tried use the same model but it did not work.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand well your question but I might have a tips.

If you need to export something using Impex. You can connect to your hMC or backoffice.
Go to System -> Tools -> Script generator.

In the popin click on generate, it will create an impex with all the headers to export all objects in hybris.

Choose in this big file the objects your interested in.

Then use the export tools (above script generator), paste the impex with the objects you need in the wizard. Then it will give you a zip to download if the export is successful.

Comment: Great, Your understanding is correct. Thank very much. Sorry me, my English isn't so good.

Comment: You're quite welcome, no problem for the english, it's not the worth I've seen.