# Deployment type-code changed from Reserved Hybris to Non-reserved codes. Do I need Update or Initialize the whole system?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I used some of the Hybris reserved Deployment code and then later changed to non-reserved deployment type codes. Do I need to Initialize the system in-order to reflect the changes with new deployment code or just an Update works. There are many items that deployment code has been changed. Why update doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

When you use a reserved code in your deployment table, you're likely to add the attributes of your object in an existing table. If you have attributes with the same name, it'll surely be a mess in the table (I don't know how hybris will choose the table type for example).

When you run an update with the good deployment code, it will create a new table which is just fine. The other table which has been used by two objects will still remain potentially broken because hybris won't delete any column.

That's why you should initialize your system to have a clean DB. The issue is that you'll lose all your data.

If you need to migrate data it will be probably quite hard because you must have to look on the broken table and distinguish between the attributes that should not be there and the others. So I hope for you that it's just a dev issue!

Answer (score 0):

Actually i would suggest you to do **initialize** rather than **update** more likely that the **update** will not work for you in this case and probably you will get some error messages saying `invalid pk xxxxxxxxxxxx because of unknown typecode yyyy`.

As you may know the `typeCode` (deployment code) is an essential operator for the generation process of `PKs` in `Hybris` and thanks to it Hybris can ensure the uniquenessity of the `PKs`, so even if you change the old `typeCode` with a new one it's very likely that `Hybris` will still keep the old `typeCode` somewhere hence `PKs` already generated will never be consistent with the new typeCode.

So that's why you should never change the typecode of an item once given.

My suggestion is :

1. To make a backup of your existing data (you can export it from HMC,
   you may take a look at alain.janinm's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42533128/how-to-export-states-in-hybris)).
2. Then initialize your System.
3. Then re-import the data again.

> Note : that typecodes between 0 and 10000 are already reserved for hybris
>   particular items.